# Can't find createAccount symbol in BankAccount project

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and creating this class which calls another class named BankAccount, and I'm getting the "cannot find symbol" error when I compile, the method is right below my main.  Any help would be great, thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InClass
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    { 
        BankAccount account;

        account = new createAccount();

    }

    public BankAccount createAccount() 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);   //input for Strings
        Scanner kb2 = new Scanner (System.in);  //input for numbers
        String strName;                         //Holds account name
        String strAccount;                      //Holds account number
        String strResponse;                         //Holds users response to account creation
        double dDeposit;                        //Holds intial deposit into checking
        BankAccount cust1;

        System.out.print ("\nWhat is the name of the account? ");
        strName = kb.nextLine();
        while (strName.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.print ("\nPlease input valid name.");

            System.out.print ("\nWhat is the name of the account?");
            strName = kb.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print ("\nWhat is your account number?");
        strAccount = kb.nextLine();
        while (strAccount.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.print ("\nPlease enter valid account number.");
            System.out.print ("\nWhat is your account number?");
            strAccount = kb.nextLine();
        }

        ......

        return cust1;
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to use the new keyword `account = new createAccount();`. Thats for invoking a classes constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a non-static method, you can change

```
account = new createAccount();
```

to

```
account = new InClass().createAccount();
```

Because the `createAccount()` method is not static, it requires an instance of the surrounding class. The `new InClass()` creates an instance.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works.  Now off to figure out how to call my BankAccount class.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ph0bolus: You don't call a class - you call *methods* in a class.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, that's what I meant. Still getting used to the vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
account = new createAccount();
```

That's not trying to call a method called `createAccount` - it's trying to call a constructor of a type called `createAccount`, and you don't have such a type.

You could write:

```
account = createAccount();
```

... but then that would fail because `createAccount` is an *instance* method instead of a static method (and you don't have an instance of `InClass` to call it on). You probably want it to be a static method.

As a side-note, I'd *strongly* recommend that you declare variables just at the point of first use, and get rid of the pseudo-Hungarian notation e.g.

```
String name = kb.nextLine();
```

instead of:

```
String strName;
...
strName = kb.nextLine();
```

In Java, you don't need to declare all your local variables at the top of a method - and doing so hurts readability.

Comment: The instructions asked for a non static createAccount method though.  Yeah, I know it's a pain to read, but my instructor is VERY old school and introduced Hungarian notation from the get-go.

Comment: @ph0bolus: In that case you'll need to create an instance of `InClass`, although it's pointless. Even if you *do* use Hungarian notation (ick), you still don't need to declare variables at the top of methods...

Answer (score 0):

The `createAccount` method is non-static and associated with the `InClass` class. In order to invoke that method, you need an instance of `InClass`. Maybe something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InClass inClass = new InClass();
    BankAccount account = inClass.createAccount();
}
```